# !PANIC!: *** Did not find any ports to use ***

Tags: dpdk

Trying to run default configuration of pkt gen DPDK and getting error did not find any ports to use. Any help will be much Appreciated. I am attaching default file of configuration and also the errors.  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js4lr.png) , [Default configuration file part 1] , [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz1DS.png) [Default configuration file part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y36q.png) ,
[NIC Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c44TS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pktgen cmdline you have shared whitelisted `05:00.0, 03:00.0, 81:00.0 & 84:00.0`. In your enviroment you have devices `00:08.0 & 00:09.0`. Please use the correct interface.